# Forwarding url parameter to CAS

Tags: java, spring, cas

Is there any way by which i can forward any parameters in the URL (query parameters) from my JAVA Client to CAS?

Example: http://www.myclient.com?name=A&age=23

Presently when my request is forwarded to CAS then the query parameters are dropped and CAS has no idea about the parameters. I want to send these parameters to CAS.

Or say i want that the service url that CAS receives is the complete url including all the parameters it has.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: are you using jasig cas ?

Comment: ok and why do you want to send those parameters to CAS ?

Comment: there are some actions that need to performed based on those parameters value.

Comment: those actions should be performed on the CAS server or you want cas to forward them to the application back ?

Comment: value of the parameters will define some actions to be taken on the cas server.

Comment: did u found the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

In CasAuthenticationEntryPoint method commence, service url is created by calling createServiceUrl(request, response) method.

This method then further calls

```
<code> 
    CommonUtils.constructServiceUrl(null, response, this.serviceProperties.getService(), null, this.serviceProperties.getArtifactParameter(), this.encodeServiceUrlWithSessionId);
</code>
```

Parameters:
request the HttpServletRequest
response the HttpServletResponse
service the configured service url (this will be used if not null)
serverName the server name to use to constuct the service url if the service param is empty
artifactParameterName the artifact parameter name to remove (i.e. ticket)
encode whether to encode the url or not (i.e. Jsession).

constructServiceUrl -> Constructs a service url from the HttpServletRequest or from the given serviceUrl. Prefers the serviceUrl provided if both a serviceUrl and a serviceName.

In my case i had provided the service url in the cas configuration file, so the check in constructServiceUrl

```
<code>
    if (CommonUtils.isNotBlank(service)) {
                return encode ? response.encodeURL(service) : service;
            }
</code>
```

simply sends back the encoded service url...without attaching the query string.
Also you can observe above that by default the null request object is sent to constructServiceUrl, so query parameter will not be considered.

Solution:
I extended CasAuthenticationEntryPoint from CasAuthenticationEntryPoint and override the method "createServiceUrl" as it was protected in the super class...made it behave the way i wanted to.